# Bash script gives warnings / errors although it works as expected. How can I edit to remove warnings / errors?

Tags: bash, pdf, convert, sh

I use the following script to batch-combine image sequences located inside sub-directories into .pdf files. It works well, but prints errors whilst operating.  I am interested in refining the script to remove the errors.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(find . -type d)
do
convert "${i}/*jpg" "${i}/*png" "${i}/*tif" "${i}/*tiff" "${i}.pdf"
done
```

Example of errors below..

```
convert: unable to open image `./*jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2712.

convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.  

convert: unable to open image `./*png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2712.  

convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.  

convert: unable to open image `./*tif': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2712.
```

And so on and so forth for every directory containing imagery.

Comment: If you are sure the script works 100%, you can easily get rid of the error messages by sending them to `/dev/null`, like `convert "${i}/*jpg" "${i}/*png" "${i}/*tif" "${i}/*tiff" "${i}.pdf" 2>/dev/null`.

Comment: does `convert` need to have the glob passed to it or should it be expanded by the shell?

Comment: i'm not sure of this, i am unfamiliar with glob and quite new to linux in general

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that if you encounter a directory with no matching image files, the glob is passed unexpanded to the convert command so you end up trying to convert files with literal name `./*jpg` , `./*png` and so on.

The usual solution for this (in bash, and other shells that support it) is to enable *null globbing*. Unfortunately in this case that just creates a different error, since now you are calling `convert` without any input files at all.

I can't think of a more elegant way of handling this except setting `nullglob`, expanding the globs in an array, and then explicitly testing whether the array is empty or not. So for example:

```
find $PWD -type d -execdir bash -c '
  shopt -s nullglob
  files=("$1"/*.jpg "$1"/*.png)
  if (( ${#files[@]} == 0 )); then 
    echo "$1: nothing to do here"
  else 
    convert "${files[@]}" "$1.pdf"
  fi' bash {} \;
```

or more compactly

```
find $PWD -type d -execdir bash -c '
  shopt -s nullglob
  files=("$1"/*.jpg "$1"/*.png)
  (( ${#files[@]} == 0 )) || convert "${files[@]}" "$1.pdf"
' bash {} \;
```

or, taking @Zanna's lead and doing away with `find` altogether:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nullglob

for f in **/*; do
  [[ -d "$f" ]] || continue
  files=( "$f"/*.jpg "$f"/*.png )
  (( ${#files[@]} != 0 )) || continue
  convert "${files[@]}" "$f.pdf"
done
```

Comment: This works beautifully (second script).  
  
How could I add the following image formats to the script?  .tif & .tiff

Comment: @BenRobins simplest way is just add them to the list of `files=( )` e.g. `files=( "$f"/*.jpg "$f"/*.png "$f"/*.tif "$f"/*.tif)` (there are more complicated ways using *extended globs*)

Answer (score 0):

The errors are caused by the absence of matching files there. But don't parse the output of `find` - use globstar and a test instead.

```
shopt -s globstar       
for i in **; do         
  [[ -d "$i" ]] &&      
  convert "$i"/*jpg "$i"/*png "$i"/*tif "$i"/*tiff "$i".pdf 2>/dev/null
done
shopt -u globstar
```

Comment: thanks for this.  unfortunately it produces exactly the same errors, eg;  

`convert: unable to open image CRYSTAL_BLACK_SILICA/*png: No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2712.`

`convert: no decode delegate for this image format @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.`

it also doesn't take the name of the sub-directories the image files are stored in as the name of the .pdf like the original script does

Comment: @BenRobins  Fixed the last part - I realise then that the errors are only because those directories don't contain any matching files. So it would probably be best to discard the errors... can't think of an easy way to test whether they exist and concatenate the data at the same time. I edited my answer but I'll delete it when I'm sure you've seen it as it's not very useful

Comment: @BenRobins Haha no worries :) it's not clever though, it's just cheating to throw the errors away. Steeldriver shows the smart ways

Comment: For now this solution works for me from a practical perspective (it works and its something I need to use several times a day).  I will however experiment with Steeldrivers method above from a learning perspective to hopefully achieve a more elegant approach.